# Using electron-forge make on Travis CI

Tags: electron, travis-ci, electron-forge

According to the Electron docs, it is recommended to run the `electron-forge make` command (to make distributables). I ran a test on Travis CI, hoping that would do the trick, but it did not seem that way. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You can find a guide for running electron-forge with Travis CI here: https://bretahajek.com/2016/11/electron-builder-appveyor-travis-ci-memory-king/

Note: I am **not** affiliated or connected with that site in anyway, and I am not responsible if anything in the guide breaks anything on your system.